# Fresh Install 14.04 Server Networking Not Working

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, wired

I just installed 14.04 server and the installer was able to connect to the internet to complete the install. However, after rebooting at the end of installation I can't connect to the network. The installer was unable to setup the network connection automatically so I had manually set that up. Right now I can't ping the router or any other computer on the local network. Does anyone have a suggestion of where to start?

This is what my /etc/network/interfaces file looks like:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.9
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

This is the output of sudo ethtool eth1:

```
Settings for eth1:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  Not reported
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Advertised auto-negotiation: No
Speed: Unknown!
Duplex: Unknown! (255)
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: off
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
Link detected: no
```

And this is the output of sudo lshw -C network:

```
  *-network:0 DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: NetXtreme BCM5703X Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 4
   bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 02
   serial: 00:0e:7f:ef:a5:df
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pcix pm vpd msi bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5703-v2.22 latency=64 link=no mingnt=64 multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:18 memory:f2cf0000-f2cfffff memory:f0040000-f004ffff
  *-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: NetXtreme BCM5703X Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:02:02.0
   logical name: eth1
   version: 02
   serial: 00:0e:7f:ef:a5:de
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pcix pm vpd msi bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5703-v2.22 ip=192.168.0.9 latency=64 link=no mingnt=64 multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:20 memory:f2ce0000-f2ceffff memory:f0050000-f005ffff
  *-network:2 DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: NetXtreme BCM5701 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:06:01.0
   logical name: eth2
   version: 15
   serial: 00:08:02:28:b1:60
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pcix pm vpd msi bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5701s-v2.19 latency=64 link=no mingnt=64 multicast=yes port=fibre
   resources: irq:21 memory:f7ff0000-f7ffffff memory:f0060000-f006ffff
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the network cable plugged in?

The UBUNTU base install assigns IPaddresses with `DHCP`. 
Unless during the install the `$USER` assigned a static IPaddress.

From the original post.

output `lshw -C network`

*-network:1
logical name: `eth1`

output `ethtool eth1`:

Settings for `eth1`:

**`Link detected:`** **`no`**

1. Check the network cable.
2. From shell prompt, enter the command `ifconfig`

*"Post that output".* `IPaddress, NETWORK, SUBNETMASK, GATEWAY, BROADCAST, DNS,`

3. From shell prompt, enter the command `hostname -I`

*"Post that output".*

4. Login to the router/modem/bridge and obtain the `IPaddress, NETWORK, SUBNETMASK, GATEWAY` of the router(s), assuming you have only one router?

*"Post  the private `IPaddress, NETWORK, SUBNETMASK, GATEWAY`"* of the router.

NOTE: **"REMOVE"** the routers public IP address: `X.X.X.X` it can be found at What is my IP Address page. (from another computer connected to your local area network LAN)

For example, if you have multiple computers within your home you may want to the private IP addresses of each computer within your home.

Your router gets the public IP address, and each of the computers, tablets and smartphones connected to your router (via wired or wifi) get a private IP address from your router or server via DHCP protocol or Statically assigned. That is beyond the scope of the question